# renaming a picture name after inserting into a database

Tags: php, mysql

thanks for helping.

I wrote a script which downloads a picture from external url and writes into server. I use mysql database to call the image destination. for this I have to follow this order:

1. Download a picture from url write into my folder
2. write the destionation into my database
3. take the last id with mysql_insert_id( $link );
4. Rename the picture. (which i don't know how to do with rename())

here is my code

```
<?php
$source_pic = $arr['thumbnail_url']; \\ comes from a API
        $destination_pic =   '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/domain.com/Uploads/thumbnails/'.uniqid($tag_ponter).'.jpg';
        $max_width = 460;
        $max_height = 345;

        $what = getimagesize($source_pic);

        switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($source_pic);
                break;
            case 'image/jpeg':
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_pic);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($source_pic);
                break;
            default: die();
        }

        list($width,$height)=getimagesize($source_pic);

        $x_ratio = $max_width / $width;
        $y_ratio = $max_height / $height;

        if( ($width <= $max_width) && ($height <= $max_height) ){
            $tn_width = $width;
            $tn_height = $height;
        }elseif (($x_ratio * $height) < $max_height){
            $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
            $tn_width = $max_width;
        }else{
            $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
            $tn_height = $max_height;
        }

        $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($tn_width,$tn_height);
        imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$tn_width, $tn_height,$width,$height);

        imagejpeg($tmp,$destination_pic,100);
        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($tmp);

        $thumbnail = '/Uploads/thumbnails/'.$tag_pointer.'.jpg';

        //Write into Database
    $values[] = "(NULL,'" . $GroupID . "','" . $UserID . "','" . $Title . "', '". $Description ."', '" . $tag_pointer . "','" . $arr['url'] . "', '". $arr['provider_name'] ."', '".$Text."', '". $arr['type'] ."', '" . $thumbnail . "', '" . $arr['html'] . "', NOW(), '0', '" . getRealIP() . "','1', '0','0')";
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contents( ContentID, CatID, UserID, Title, Description, Tag, Link, Provider, Text, Type, Thumbnail, Html, WriteTime, Comments, WriterIP, Active, TotalVotes, VoteSum ) 
                             VALUES  ".implode(',', $values)."");

    $ContentID = mysql_insert_id( $link );
 ?>
```

how do I rename the file? and is this right thing to do?

Comment: rename the file in filesystem ? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.rename.php

Comment: rename the file in filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to rename what's stored in the database, or rename the actual file on the file system so I'll show you how to do both:

**Rename on Filesystem**

You can use the rename function:

```
rename("/path/OLD_FILE.png", "/path/NEW_RENAME_FILE.png");
```

*or*

The following code is responsible for saving to the filesystem:

```
imagejpeg($tmp,$destination_pic,100);
```

Notice the $destination_pic? This is where your file will be stored, including the filename. As such, you need to ensure that $destination_pic is defined as follows:

```
$destination_pic =   '/some/path/'. $YOUR_RENAMED_FILE .'.jpg';
```

***Rename in DB***

I presume *Title* is the name of the file in the database? In that case, you'll need to run an update query to change it.

```
UPDATE your_table SET TITLE='$RENAMED_TITLE'
```

Comment: i was asking for the file system. thank you for your answer. that helped a lot.